# Android USB Vendor IDs for unknown brand

Tags: android, debugging, sdk, usb

Refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#VendorIds, I want to buy a unknown brand Android device, such as http://app-4-android.blogspot.com/2011/09/ainol-novo-8-android-22-8-in-tablet.html, How can I get the USB Vendor ID? Can it be used to develop Android App?

Please advise.

Answer (score 10):

try `lsusb` command on linux terminal, this show you the vendor id

Comment: In combination with @Phill's useful and simple answer try this: [blog post](http://ptspts.blogspot.in/2011/10/how-to-fix-adb-no-permissions-error-on.html). Worked for me with a cheap and obscure android device today.

Answer (score 5):

you can use google vid  18d1. It worked for me.