# Connecting to Android device via USB to install apps from Eclipse

Tags: android, ubuntu, usb

I've got a cheap Android device, and I can't connect it to my Ubuntu 11.10 laptop via USB. When I connect the USB cable, I don't see any notification on the Android, and nothing appears in the list of devices from `adb`.

```
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 

$
```

When I run `lsusb` before connecting the device and after, I see no new USB devices.

The device is running Android 4.0.3, and I enabled USB debugging under Settings: System: Developer options.

I tried following the instructions for [configuring USB rules](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) under `/etc/udev/rules.d/`, but I don't know the vendor id for my device. I wrote a small program to display `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER`, but it was "unknown". `android.os.Build.MODEL` was "P90", so I think I have a P90 from T&R as discussed in [this forum](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/31562-eken-a90-advanced-97-ips-8000mah-battery/page__st__420), or maybe from Eken. I tried using Google's vendor id as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9608812/4794), but it didn't change anything.

I will try another cable, but until I get my hands on a new cable, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Did you get this solved? How?

Comment: No, @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun, I ended up using a different Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the USB Debugging option in Preferences > Developer options? Without that I don't think your device will show up.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled USB debugging. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this from your device :

```
Settings > Applications > Development > Enable USB debugging mode.
```

or there may be somewhat different menu on your device but you need to Enable USB debugging mode first. Then unplug your device and plug again. You will see your device listed on lsusb.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled USB debugging. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install usb driver software in your machine and restart eclipse, your device will detect in eclipse to install your app

Comment: According to [this page](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html), you only need USB drivers on Windows, not Linux.

Comment: ooh sorry, if you find the solution, post here.

Answer (score 0):

It's sad, but another cable is the only solution. I've tested it just a few minutes ago. 1 computer, 1 USB-port, 1 phone and 2 cables. With some manipulation on original cable near phone's port I can get info on phone's screen that it's in debug mode. But there is no such info on computer. And with another cable everything is okay.

**Note**: Few hours ago the phone worked with original cable.